# How to fix " Error: GraphQL error: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am trying to fully connect react with graphql server. I didn't have problem with getting queries from mongodb, but I have problem with mutation. Actually I see some changes

[in my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVFB3.jpg)

but it retrieves error from the question in the title. Also, *rendered by* tab in console is different from the tab of "ninja graphql tutorial project" from which I have been learning so I am pretty confused if I am setup code correctly in first place.

My setup:

queries.js

```js
export const addUserMutation = gql`
  mutation createUser($input: UserInput) {
    createUser(input: $input) {
      firstName
      lastName
      email
      items {
        text
        timeISO
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

app.js

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhost:5000/graphql"
});

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
        <Route exact path="/users" component={UsersList} />
        <Route exact path="/adduser" component={AddUser} />
      </ApolloProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

addUser.js

```js
import { graphql } from "react-apollo";
import * as compose from "lodash.flowright";

import { addUserMutation } from "../queries/queries";

const AddUser = props => {
  let [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  let [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
  let [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  let [gender, setGender] = useState("MALE");
  let [items, setItems] = useState("");
  const onChange = e => {
    if (e.target.name === "firstName") {
      setFirstName(e.target.value);
    }
    if (e.target.name === "lastName") {
      setLastName(e.target.value);
    }
    if (e.target.name === "email") {
      setEmail(e.target.value);
    }
    if (e.target.name === "items") {
      setItems(e.target.value);
    }
    if (e.target.name === "gender") {
      setGender(e.target.value);
    }
  };
  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(props);
    props.addUserMutation({
      variables: {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        gender,
        items
      }
    });
    return (....)
  };
export default compose(graphql(addUserMutation, { name: "addUserMutation" }))(
  AddUser
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please set response parameter in createUser mutation .Please see below example:

```
mutation createUser($input: UserInput) {
    createUser(input: $input) {
      firstName
      lastName
      email
      items {
        text
        timeISO
        title
      }
    } Response
  }

type Response {
_id:String
name:String
}
```

** type keyword use for return response data